# Best way to export a database table to a YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have some data in my development database that I would like to utilize as fixtures in my test environment.  What is the best way in Rails 2.x to export a database table to a YAML fixture?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a rake task for this. You can specify RAILS_ENV if needed; the default is the development environment:

```
rake db:fixtures:dump
    # Create YAML test fixtures from data in an existing database.
```

Comment: db:fixtures:dump on Rails? I don't see it on 2.3.5.

Comment: looks like it's been extracted from ActiveRecord.  You can add it back with this plugin:

http://github.com/topfunky/ar_fixtures

Then run: rake db:fixtures:dump MODEL=ModelName

Comment: this is only valid for Rails 3.

Comment: Does 'rake db:fixtures:dump' impact the current database in any way? Or just export to YAML?

Answer (score 21):

I have been using YamlDb to save the state of my database.

Install it with the following command:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db.git
```

Use the rake task to dump the contents of Rails database to db/data.yml

```
rake db:data:dump
```

Use the rake task to load the contents of db/data.yml into the database

```
rake db:data:load
```

This is the creators homepage:

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2007/11/23/yamldb_for_databaseindependent_data_dumps/

Comment: how can one target a table to dump, instead of dumping the entire db?

Answer (score 9):

This plugin will add the functionality you want.  It was extracted from ActiveRecord so no longer comes by default.

`script/plugin install http://github.com/topfunky/ar_fixtures`

Then run:

`rake db:fixtures:dump MODEL=ModelName`

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 3, if you want to dump yaml from the DB and use it as a fixture, I use this code:

```
module DbToFixture

  TEMP_FIXTURE_PATH = Rails.root.join("test", "new_fixtures")

  def fixturize(model)
    Dir.mkdir(TEMP_FIXTURE_PATH) unless File.exists?(TEMP_FIXTURE_PATH)
    fname = model.table_name
    file_path = TEMP_FIXTURE_PATH.join(fname)
    File.open(file_path, 'w') do |f|
      model.all.each do |m|
        f.write(m.to_yaml)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I just run it from the console with

```
require './lib/db_to_fixture'
include DbToFixture
fixturize ModelName
```

I have not been able to get ar_fixtures to work with Rails 3 (haven't tried very hard though).  Yaml db is great for dumping and saving the db, but its format is not compatible with fixtures.

Comment: Do I name the file db_to_fixture? It's amazing Rails doesn't have a simple one-line command to do in the latest rails. This is something I need to do often.

Comment: It is amazing.  In any case, yes, it has to be the snake case of whatever the module is called.

Answer (score 4):

[Iron Fixture Extractor](https://github.com/joegoggins/iron_fixture_extractor) was built for exactly this purpose.  It's particularly good for situations where you want to use different fixture sets for different testing scenarios (rather than having all fixtures for all tests).  It provides functionality for extracting, loading, rebuilding fixtures, truncating tables, or snagging particular hashes from your fixture yaml files.

Comment: Thank you for this great recommendation. I found it particularly useful since it allowed me to extract just a portion of data for test purposes on a fairly large table.

Answer (score 2):

`rake db:fixtures:dump`

has been changed to

`rake db:extract_fixtures`

Comment: for which version of rails?  this doesn't seem to be true for 2.x, which the question was asked of.  perhaps your answer is specific to rails 3.x?

Comment: It's not in vanilla Rails 3.x either.

Comment: Doesn't work. Are you using some library that adds this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

```
 > rails c
 irb> puts Modelname.all.to_yaml
```

then copy & paste it in file and edit it to match what fixtures expect.

It's manual labor but if you need this just once probably the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple gem will create yaml fixtures from existing database...

[github.com/vanboom/yaml_dump](https://github.com/vanboom/yaml_dump)

Works with Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rake task that will do exactly that (tested in Rails 3.2.8):

```
namespace :db do
    task :extract_fixtures => :environment do
      sql  = 'SELECT * FROM "%s"'
      skip_tables = ["schema_migrations"]
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
      if (not ENV['TABLES'])
        tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - skip_tables
      else
        tables = ENV['TABLES'].split(/, */)
      end
      if (not ENV['OUTPUT_DIR'])
        output_dir="#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures"
      else
        output_dir = ENV['OUTPUT_DIR'].sub(/\/$/, '')
      end
      (tables).each do |table_name|
        i = "000"
        File.open("#{output_dir}/#{table_name}.yml", 'w') do |file|
          data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql % table_name.upcase)
          file.write data.inject({}) { |hash, record|
            hash["#{table_name}_#{i.succ!}"] = record
            hash
          }.to_yaml
          puts "wrote #{table_name} to #{output_dir}/"
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Source: http://sachachua.com/blog/2011/05/rails-exporting-data-specific-tables-fixtures/

Note: I had to make a few changes to the blog code to make it more cross-database compatible and work in Rails 3.2

Comment: Nice script. I had to remove the '.upcase' to make it work in Rails 4 but otherwise, it works as advertised. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in Rails 6:

```
# How to run:
# rake fixtures:import_db_table[my_table]
namespace :fixtures do
  desc 'Convert development table into Rails test fixtures'
  task :import_db_table, [:table_name] => :environment do |_task, args|
    begin
      table_name = args[:table_name]
      raise "Missing table name" if table_name.blank?
      conter = '000'
      file_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml"
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
      File.open(file_path, 'w') do |file|
        rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM #{table_name}")
        data = rows.each_with_object({}) do |record, hash|
          suffix = record['id'].blank? ? conter.succ! : record['id']
          hash["#{table_name.singularize}_#{suffix}"] = record
        end
        puts "Writing table '#{table_name}' to '#{file_path}'"
        file.write(data.to_yaml)
      end
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close if ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    end
  end
end
```

Extracted from [here](https://yizeng.me/2017/07/16/generate-rails-test-fixtures-yaml-from-database-dump/) (which imports all tables).

Answer (score 0):

For dumping for rspec/cucumber test fixtures in Rails 3 this is the best answer I've found:
[What is the standard way to dump db to yml fixtures in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325865/what-is-the-standard-way-to-dump-db-to-yml-fixtures-in-rails)