# What is the standard way to dump db to yml fixtures in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I've seen some plugins and custom rake tasks to dump the active db to fixtures, but I'm not sure what the prevailing technique is.

Basically, I want the opposite of rake:db:fixtures:load so that I can put basic db information (the admin user account, for one) into svn for when we deploy. I don't want to have to create fixtures manually for things like sample data that would take a long time.

When we deploy I want to be able to just run

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:fixtures:load
```

And be off to the races.

What is the best/preferred method for doing this in rails?

EDIT:

So it seems there is no standard way to do an opposite rake task of db:fixtures:load.

I don't want to use migrations, because I want a standard way of doing this for all my projects, and I don't like the idea of putting any more than maybe the admin account in a migration. Second, I've been rethinking the idea of using the fixtures. I've decided on using yaml_db because it uses rake tasks:

```
rake db:data:dump
rake db:data:load
```

The data will wind up in a YAML file without distrupting test fixtures (which could be different, now that I think about this more carefully). Also, if a major distribution tool like Heroku is using it, I don't have to worry about support/longevity issues.

I suppose this is closest to "standard" that I will find.

Thanks for all the great responses.

Comment: @Hari: Rails 3 didn't even exist when this question was written and answered; presumably neither is specific to that version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heroku uses the YamlDB Gem

http://www.github.com/ludicast/yaml_db/tree/master

Comment: If you are using Heroku than you can go with taps: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

Comment: YamlDB is great for dumping databases and reloading them.  However, the YAML format is not compatible with fixtures.

Comment: Sorry this is absolute nonsense.. Why shouldnt be the YAML foramt compatible with fixtures? Look http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html

Comment: Sorry, let me be more precise.  The YAML format created by YamlDB is different from the YAML format used for fixtures.  YamlDB starts with <table_name>: which then contains columns: then records: which contains lines for each for each field listed in columns: for each record.  The format for fixtures is simply the record key (eg users1) followed directly by key/value pairs for the fields, eg id: 1, user_name: bob etc.  No listing of column names or other meta data.

Comment: @jpgeek is correct. No idea why this aswer was upvoted; YamlDB is related, do is useless in this case. The answer detailing a Rake task code is the correct one.

Answer (score 16):

This sounds like you should be using db/seeds.rb, and the related rake db:seed task.  These are designed specifically for loading seed data.  You can then make calls to [YamlDB](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) 
to load the data and rake db:data:dump_dir to dump all fixtures to a temporary directory and copy them over to your seed data directory as needed.

Note that this does NOT work for dumping fixtures, as the YAML format is different.  ar_fixtures noted above does not work with Rails 3 and does not seem to be supported any more.  For dumping fixtures, you might want to try something like this in lib/tasks/dump_fixtures.rake:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :fixtures do    
    desc 'Create YAML test fixtures from data in an existing database.  
    Defaults to development database.  Specify RAILS_ENV=production on command line to override.'
    task :dump => :environment do
      sql  = "SELECT * FROM %s"
      skip_tables = ["schema_migrations"]
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env)
      (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - skip_tables).each do |table_name|
        i = "000"
        File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml.new", 'w') do |file|
          data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql % table_name)
          file.write data.inject({}) { |hash, record|
            hash["#{table_name}_#{i.succ!}"] = record
            hash
          }.to_yaml
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I found this [here](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=5970) and modified it slightly for Rails3.

Comment: Also in new versions of Rails you have to change the RAILS_ENV to Rails.env.

Comment: Why .yml.new (as opposed to .yml)

Comment: Man, thank you so much. I've been hunting for a straight solution for over an hour.  For anyone trying to load fixture for Cucumber tests combine the above with this: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Fixtures, but be sure to alter one or the other so they reference the same fixtures folder...

Comment: Should be skipping the table `schema_migrations` not `schema_info`

Answer (score 2):

there is no **Standard** way to do it. Only a standard way to load fixtures:

```
rake db:fixtures:load
```

But there are plenty of examples on the internet:

- http://fukamachi.org/wp/2007/05/18/rails-dump-database-to-fixtures-preserving-utf8/
- http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4468
- [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=rails+dump+database+fixtures&btnG=Search) :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't use exactly the same format as db:fixtures:load would expect, but [ar_fixtures](http://github.com/topfunky/ar_fixtures/tree/master) makes dumping and loading data as YAML files pretty easy.

Comment: ar_fixtures doesn't work with Rails 3 and does not seem to be supported any more.

Answer (score 1):

I think if is the the standard admin information you might be better off to put that in the migrations. fixtures should ideally be used only for testing.

Comment: If there is any more data than an admin account, I don't like the idea of using migrations. I want a standard procedure for all my rails projects.

Comment: You are right about only using fixtures for testing, though. The more I thought about this, the more I realized the data should be in a separate file from fixtures or migrations.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else just finding this now I've slightly modified the answer from @jpgeek.  Include the `schema_migration` table in the ignore list and order by ID so the output I get is `table_name_001` for `ID=1`

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :fixtures do    
    desc 'Create YAML test fixtures from data in an existing database.  
    Defaults to development database.  Specify RAILS_ENV=production on command line to override.'
    task :dump => :environment do
      sql  = "SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY ID"
      skip_tables = ["schema_info", "schema_migrations"]
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env)
      (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - skip_tables).each do |table_name|
        i = "000"
        File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml.new", 'w') do |file|
          data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql % table_name)
          file.write data.inject({}) { |hash, record|
            hash["#{table_name}_#{i.succ!}"] = record
            hash
          }.to_yaml
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```