# Export a db-table to yaml

Tags: database, export, yaml

I'm trying to generate test data for my integration tests. Therefore I need to export db-tables into a yaml-files. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Are you already using a programing language for this project?

Comment: There are two possible options. Java and Scala.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/490507/741249