# Rails 4: Export database to YAML

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

With Rails 2/3 it was possible and easy to export (dump) a database to YAML using one of a few  plugins (see [Best way to export a database table to a YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490507/best-way-to-export-a-database-table-to-a-yaml-file)).

However, none of these plugins seem to be compatible with Rails 4. Is there still an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The method indicated in the post linked in the question is still valid, but the code is not anymore a plugin: it's the yaml_db gem.

The repository is at https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db

To dump the db, add the gem to the Gemfile, issue

```
bundle update
```

and then issue:

```
rake db:data:dump
```

the dump file is:

```
db/data.yml
```

If, like me, you hit the error

```
undefined method `[]=' for #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x007ff34c76d508>
```

it can be fixed by following the instructions given in this ticket:

https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db/pull/45

All you should have to do is add

```
gem 'yaml_db', github: 'jetthoughts/yaml_db', ref: 'fb4b6bd7e12de3cffa93e0a298a1e5253d7e92ba'
```

to the Gemfile

Comment: This gem appears to be stagnant and does not work on Rails 4.x

Comment: It does work in rails 4 if you follow the instructions on that pull request.

Comment: @darioshanghai : Thanks, It works for me on rails 4. by just giving ref to gem.

Comment: There is a new repo for yaml_db at https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db which supports Rails 3 & 4.