# Rails database empty after cloning from another computer via GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, github

I just cloned a rails project I've been working on but unfortunately when I went to modify some of the pre-existing records from my models the database appears to have no recollection of them. While my models are still in-tact its their instances that are not. I did the proper procedure of bundling, and running a migration but no luck. Is there something I'm missing to retrieve these records that were saved on my other computer?

**Update:**

I've just come to realization that I would most likely have to seed the database to retrieve my records. Correct me if I'm wrong but if I were to go this route that would mean that I'd have to manually input each instance of my model within the seed file. Is there a better way to do this especially if you have a large database?

Answer (score 0):

in my rails app i have a bootstrap.rake file that sets the basic database values that are created upon the initial roll out / installation of the app.

the file lives in rails_app_directory/lib/tasks/bootstrap.rake

do you have anything like this?

this is an example of the kind of code included in the file....

```
desc "Set a standard layout"
  task :default_page_layouts => :environment do
    puts "Loading default (standard) page layout."

    PageLayout.create(:name=>"Standard", :filename => 'standard', :description => "Standard page layout")
    PageLayout.create(:name=>"Main", :filename => 'main', :description => "Main/Home page layout")
    PageLayout.create(:name=>"Testimonials", :filename => 'testimonials', :description => "For viewing all approved testimonials.")
    PageLayout.create(:name=>"Events", :filename => 'events', :description => "For viewing all events.")
    PageLayout.create(:name=>"Content", :filename => 'content', :description => "For viewing individual content items.")
  end
end
```

in this case, the table "page_layouts" has the fields "name", "filename" and "description"

Comment: if you have an exceptionally large database that needs to be repopulated, i would imagine you could create a sql_dump file with the required initial data, and then upon installation of the new rails app, the dump file could be used to automatically generate the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

For my updated question I ended up choosing the gem, [Yamldb](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) and followed instructions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490507/best-way-to-export-a-database-table-to-a-yaml-file). If anyone knows of any better alternatives I'm all ears.